# Filtered image is bigger than original image in file size - LiipImagineBunle

Tags: symfony, liipimaginebundle

My goal is to generate an image from one original uploaded image. I am using the built-in `relative_resize` filter of `LiipImagineBundle`.

The configuration of the bundle:

```
my_filter:
     filters:
        relative_resize: { widen: 960 }
```

Let's say : for an image filename  `image.jpeg` that is 1280*850, I am having an additional filtered file `b_image.jpg`.The problem is that `b_image.jpg`, which is 960*640 is way bigger in file size than `image.jpg`.

Do you have any suggestions regarding how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no suggestion to how to debug this issue, but I suggest to use `quality` options in your filters. Just try many options and watch the results.

One of my nice filter:

```
my_filter:
        quality:              70
        jpeg_quality:         70
        png_compression_level: 9
        png_compression_filter: ~
        format:               jpg
        filters:
            auto_rotate: ~
            thumbnail: { size: [960, 1500], mode: inset }
            strip: ~
            interlace:
                mode: plane
```