# Convert format while doing thumbnail

Tags: symfony, liipimaginebundle, php-imagine

I'm using LiipImagineBundle to make thumbnails for images uploaded by users. So far so good. Today I discovered that some users are uploading tiff images, that are not displayed in most modern browsers. So, I'd want to convert thumbnails for such files in other format (e.g. in png), but I'm stuck between loaders and filters. I can possibly use imagick.

Comment: Use `format` option. One of my setup that works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845881/3675759

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it's not working. I get an error complaining that "Source image could not be found". It looks like it's searching for foo.png (while image is foo.tiff)

Comment: Thanks @malcolm , solution worked for me for PNG -> JPEG